# Dont have relieving letter from my first company

Tags: india, background-check, relieving-letter

I have total experience of 2.7 years. In that experience, I have worked in two companies. I have experience of 1.6 years in my first company which was a very small company. They used to torture me by working 14 hours a day and they are also not giving increment after that. Not a single thing was good there. So I decided to join another company. I put resignation them but they didn't accept my resignation. And also said me that you have to stay for next 4 months illegally. So I decided to left without relieving letter and my second company accepted that. Now I am getting offers from big MNCs. But I know that they all will ask for relieving letter from all previous employers. I have all docs of the second company. But don't have a relieving letter of the first company. But I have salary slips, bank statements, offer letter, increment letter. So should I tell this thing to my next company's HR which is an MNC(Multi National Company). Will they accept me?

Comment: Even if you don't have a relieving letter, your future company would do a background check.  So, you're busted in any way.  So, act smart and take that relieving letter.

Comment: @Dawny33 But they are not ready to give me relieving letter and also not ready to settle down with money. At this point what should I do ?

Comment: @AmitDas No other option except to play the bigger guy here, and walk out gracefully (of course, along with your letter).

Comment: @Dawny33 Will HCL accept me without relieving letter ?

Comment: Nope. Even if they don't need one, they'd definitely do a background check, which obviously wouldn't turn out to be good.

Comment: @Dawny33 If I understand correctly, it was not the OP's current employer but the one before that who did not provide the relieving letter.  I'm not sure how the OP is supposed to obtain that now.

Comment: @Dawny33  But i have all other documents and i will tell the truth to HCl. Then what will happen

Comment: @Dawny33 They are not ready to give me relieving letter. Please suggest me.

Comment: @JaneS In that case, the post you've linked to, should answer this question. [Marked as duplicate] :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, the first employer was a hellhole, refused to accept his resignation, and he left without the relieving letter.  The second employer is OK, and he is on good terms with them, and a relieving letter from them will not be a problem.

He is now under consideration by a multinational corporation, who will do a background check, and the background check will reveal the lack of the first receiving letter.

This is where you go proactive.  Disclose the facts to the MNC (multinational corporation), BEFORE they start the background check, so they hear it FROM YOU, FIRST.  Don't go into invective, simply explain what went down with the first employer, and explain that you felt you had no reasonable alternative but to leave without the letter.  It is my understanding that even India prohibits slavery.

Odds are good they'll see your side of it, and not hold the lack of the relieving letter against you.

It is entirely possible that the MNC already knows about that first employer, from other people, and knows they are a hellhole.  Word DOES get around.  In that event, it is entirely possible that leaving them without the relieving letter just might count in your favor, showing that you have courage, gumption, and that quality sometimes known as "cojones", in that you were willing to walk out and take your chances, rather than bend over and take it.

Disclosure can't hurt you in this case.  You're telling them something they're going to find out ANYWAY.  It can only help, by showing you are honest, up-front, and have the courage to do the right thing.

Comment: And provide an alternate method to verify your employment such as pay slips and copy of resignation letter.